# Substring specific integer from string

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have google some related questions, but unfortunately didn't find answer.

I have string like `2016-07-22`, i need to get an integer `07`, evaluate it to 7 and save.

Of course, this is date, therefore it will change every time, so i cant suppose that year always will be 2016. I need to get string after 5th symbol up to 8th.

Is there any easy way to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always that section of the string, you can use `NSMakeRange(5, 2)` and `substringWithRange` to pick out the month.

After you have "07", conversion is just a case of asking the string for its `integerValue`.

The "save" part depends entirely on where you want to save it.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is just one way (I can think of at least 3 other ways):

```
NSString *str = @"2016-07-22";
NSArray *elements = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSAssert([elements count] == 3, @"Ahhh!");
NSInteger month = [elements[1] integerValue];
```